# Issue with Laravel Eloquent query, but the built query works when executed manually

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

I am working on a Laravel API where I am using Eloquent to access a MySQL database with a couple of joins and a group by clause.

When Eloquent runs I get an error, but the error outputs the built SQL which when I run manually on the database, it works fine, so I'm a little confused what the problem might be.

The Eloquent query builder is as follows:

```
$issues = \DB::table('crash_groups')
                ->join('projects', 'projects.project_id', '=', 'crash_groups.project_id')
                ->join('crash_info', 'crash_info.crash_group_id', '=', 'crash_groups.crash_group_id')
                ->where('projects.organisation_id', $organisation_id)
                ->where('crash_info.created_at', '>', $time_interval_sql)
                ->groupBy('crash_info.crash_group_id')
                ->get();
```

When the above is executed I get the following error outputted

> SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1055
> 'crash_groups.crash_group_id' isn't in GROUP BY
> (SQL: select * from `crash_groups` inner join `projects` on
> `projects`.`project_id` = `crash_groups`.`project_id` inner join
> `crash_info` on `crash_info`.`crash_group_id` =
> `crash_groups`.`crash_group_id` where `projects`.`organisation_id` = 1
> and `crash_info`.`created_at` > NOW() - INTERVAL 1 DAY group by
> `crash_info`.`crash_group_id`)

If I manually take the SQL query that is within the error log and run that directly in the database, I then get 2 rows back as I am expecting so I don't understand why I'm getting an SQL error about the Group By when Eloquent executes when the query that it actually builds and logs as being an issue actually works.

Comment: Try and enable query logging to see the full generated query:

```
Db::enableQueryLog()
<your code>
Db::disableQueryLog()
```
Its very likley something autogenerated since its quite complex statement.

Comment: sorry, i didnt read full question and missed parts. Can it be you have two different connections? Like running sqlite from code? Another thing might be you have some connection variable.

Comment: @PatrikGrinsvall no worries, no different databases, just has a single database setup and I'm only ever user the default one without providing a connection name to access it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Correct answer for this question is to either include the columns in a select like

```
$issues = \DB::table('crash_groups')
                ->select('crash_info.crash_group_id')
                ->join('projects', 'projects.project_id', '=', 'crash_groups.project_id')
                ->join('crash_info', 'crash_info.crash_group_id', '=', 'crash_groups.crash_group_id')
                ->where('projects.organisation_id', $organisation_id)
                ->where('crash_info.created_at', '>', $time_interval_sql)
                ->groupBy('crash_info.crash_group_id')
                ->get();
```

Another way is to disable mysql strict mode.
To disable strict mode, edit in in config/database.php.

```
'mysql' => [ 
'strict' => false, //'strict' => true, 
],
```

Comment: Still seem to be getting the same issue, the only difference as you mentioned instead of `group by 'crash_info'.'crash_group_id'` its now `group by crash_info.crash_group_id`.

One thing I have noticed is though in the SQL error it says `crash_groups.crash_group_id` isn't in the group by, when i'm grouping by `crash_info.crash_group_id` so why is the error referring to a different table to what i'm grouping against

Comment: alright, this is then likey due to strict mode. There is a config option to database connection that has strict true/false and if i recall correct you can also set this as config to mysql server.

Comment: try this in config/database. 'mysql' => [
            'strict' => false,
            //'strict' => true,
        ], reference: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-handling.html

Comment: Ah yea that's fixed, what does that strict option mean, had a quick google but couldn't find anything specific, just some vague forums?

Comment: Its for avoiding sql injections i guess. Its so its not possible to modify the query throught the group by statement. I will update answer.